# Impute Missing Values with Caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I am working on the Kaggle Titanic competition and I have a question regarding imputing missing values.  I am trying to use the Caret package and my training set consists of factors as well as numbers.

I want to use the `preProcess` function in Caret to impute the missing values, but before using preProcess, I need to convert all my factors into dummy variables with the `dummyVars` function.

```
dummies  = dummyVars(survived ~ . -1, data = train, na.action = na.pass)
xtrain = predict(dummies, train)
```

However, in the process of using `dummyVars` to convert the factors, all the NAs are predicted by some unknown algorithm and the missing `age` columns all become 1's even though I have specified `na.action = na.pass`.  I want to convert my factors into dummy variables WITHOUT having the NAs touched so I can use then use the `preProcess` function to impute them.  How can I do this?

Thank you.

dput here:

```
structure(list(survived = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), pclass = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), 
    age = c(22, 38, 26, 35, 35, NA, 54, 2, 27, 14, 4, 58, 20, 
    39, 14, 55, 2, NA, 31, NA), sibsp = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0), parch = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), fare = c(7.25, 
    71.2833, 7.925, 53.1, 8.05, 8.4583, 51.8625, 21.075, 11.1333, 
    30.0708, 16.7, 26.55, 8.05, 31.275, 7.8542, 16, 29.125, 13, 
    18, 7.225), embarked = structure(c(4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "C", "Q", "S"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("survived", 
"pclass", "sex", "age", "sibsp", "parch", "fare", "embarked"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

This first part is a bug; the NA values should not be 1's (obviously). In the meantime, you can use `model.matrix` to generate the dummy variables, but you might have to do this at once for all of the data. Also, if you are using `train`, you can use the formula method. Overall, that is a better approach.

I'll fix this in the next few weeks. I'm about to release a version of caret and this, plus UseR, will delay me a bit.

EDIT: a new version will be released in the next week that fixes the bug

Max

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  `model.matrix` doesn't seem to do the trick either because it omits any rows with NA in it.  Please let me know if there's a way to get it to work.  Thanks.